# Remove publish date and comments in woocommerce products

Tags: date, woocommerce, comments, publish

How can i Remove the publish date and comments link on my products page in woocommerce?

I never understood why would a customer needs to see when a shop adds a product.

Googled a lot and all i found was links how to disable it in wordrpess itself and not in woocommerce. (Google unfortunatly isn't what it used to be).

Also found this solution but have no idea how to do this:

You can use display:none; property in css to hide date & author.

Example:

.theclassname {display: none;}

Answer (score 0):

This is just a CSS line that helps you to show, edit or hide an element in your webapp. You have to provide more details to help you exactly with what you need.

You can use this in general:

```
.theclassname {
 display: none;
 }
```

theclassname is different from theme to theme but I think you cannot use or find your necessary class name to make it work correct

You have search your theme options if has the possibility to change this feature in options/settings?

Also you can provide us your URL?